# wicked_pdf https image url not rendering in pdf file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I am rendering dynamic HTML content in pdf file using wicked pdf gem. The problem I am facing is the image is not rendering into generated pdf. source URL is forcefully redirected to HTTPS instead of HTTP. Is there any way out to render the https link from wicked pdf gem

I had tried to hit image URL manually on the browser is forcefully redirected to HTTPS instead of HTTP
http://designmodo.com/demo/emailtemplate/images/header-background.jpg

Answer (score 0):

What's your wkhtmltopdf version installed?

If you downgrade to the `0.9.9.3` version it should work. The problem with https headers appeared at the `0.12.x`.

I'm using `wicked_pdf (1.4.0)` with `gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '~> 0.9.9.3'` and it works.